# checkboxes in uitableview are giving errors

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 sections and I am trying to make it so when you click the checkbox of a cell in one of the sections, it goes to the other section (ex: section 1->section 2)

here is some relevant code of mine:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if([indexPath section] == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxtry2.png"];
    } else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];
     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxtry2selected.png"];
    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlechecking:)];
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return cell;
}


 -(void)handlechecking:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)t{
    CGPoint tapLocation = [t locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = nil;
    if (tappedIndexPath.section == 0) {
        [completedArray addObject:[taskArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
        [taskArray removeObject:[taskArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tappedIndexPath.row inSection:1];
    }
    else {
        [taskArray addObject:[completedArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
        [completedArray removeObject:[completedArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tappedIndexPath.row inSection:0];
    }
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tappedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

I have two arrays: taskArray which handles objects in section 0 and completedArray which handles objects in section 1.

I am getting the error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: The array that you are using is empty. Check the way you are creating it and populate it. Also you can use @dorada solution to find the proper cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things.

- You are adding gesture recognisers repeatedly to your table view cells even when they have been re-used and already have one.

Also in your gesture recogniser target you could do something like this which might be more reliable:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[t.view superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: im getting an error "incompatible pointer types initializing UITableViewCell *__strong with an expresssion of type UIView *

Comment: and to fix the first thing should i just put the initializiation of the gesture where the reuse identifer is?